# Save grid data to database

Tags: java, mysql

I've searched a bit on StackOverflow but none of the answers were satisfying to me (the search wasn't exhaustive).

I have a grid on my program. I'd like to save the grid data into my database however if I just create simple columns for every entry I end up with 180 columns which is horrible to maintain.

I'm not quite sure how to do this and honestly databases aren't really my area.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh I have no code at this moment, basically I have an object that has information on a 12x15 grid and I'm wondering on the most efficient way to save it to a MySQL database.

Comment: Could you please show us your design of the table? Why do you have such a lot of columns? Something is wrong with your design I guess....

Comment: The thing is I don't have a table yet, I have a Java object which is a table with 12 rows and 15 columns. My question is how to efficiently save this data to a table in a MySQL database (the table in the program is not related in anyway to a database table).

Comment: What data are you trying to store? You know that each field needs a specific data type?

Comment: My issue is not with the data types, my issue is on how to design the table in the database. For instance the dumb way would be to create a 180-column table in the database and just save the data by calculating the index however I don't feel that's a good approach.

Comment: consider a database table that has only three columns:  table_row, table_col and value.  There will then be one row in the table for every element in the grid (and not one row per table row).  If can post more details in an answer if you agree with the approach.

Comment: I've considered your approach and I think it's a great one but what if the table row and table column are strings? Wouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: If there is a mix of strings and other types, you can create a fourth table column which stores the grid data type for that element.  If all the value types are the same there is no issue.

Comment: They're all strings, please post more details about this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table (grid_values) structure would look like:

```
grid_id (int)
grid_row_id (int)
grid_col_id (int)
grid_value (varchar(??))
```

There would be a unique constraint on (grid_id, grid_row_id, grid_col_id)

Now you have a two dimensional java array like String[][] gridValues.  To store the data you have a nested loop like:

```
for (int i=0; i < NO_OF_GRID_ROWS; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j < NO_OF_GRID_COLS; j++) {
      // Save to database where i->grid_row_id, j->grid_col_id, gridValues[i][j] -> grid_value
    }
}
```

Reading in the grid would be the reverse logic.
This should work?

Comment: Can you explain why (grid_row_id,grid_col_id) should have a unique constraint? Wouldn't that limit me if I add several tables to the MySQL table? In that case shouldn't I do (id_table,grid_row_id,grid_col_id) a unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If  you have multiple grids, then grid_id  becomes part of your unique constraint.  Well done.

Comment: There's no problem using this approach of the table_row and table_col come from other tables correct?

Comment: No problem so long as you can associate grid_id to the structure of the grid you are using.  If this becomes a problem, you may need to create a grid_table_description table, to store more information about a particular grid (i.e. how many rows and cols it has, etc)

Comment: The issue I'm thinking is because the table rows on the program may grow (they represent treated pathologies of the patient and as such there's a minimal number but it may grow).

Comment: As long as it grows in a managed way it is not a problem.  Do you always know what col=150 represents?  And then col 151 when it grows?

Comment: That would depend on the number of pathologies that can be treated in the specific country but usually 12 are always available and 5/8 are available if you travel to specific areas of the globe so yes, any growth is always mapped to a specific pathology.